# Getting most power from low voltage solar powers, each different angle

Tags: power, solar-cell, low-power, energy, mppt

I have a specific problem. I have 10 small solar panels, each max 5.5V and 100mW power. Each one is at a different angle. I want to get the most power out of it. Cost is not really a problem, but I do appreciate a simple design.

I was thinking of a MPPT controller with an ideal diode at the end for each of the panels, then connecting all of them in parallel. I guess that would work, but worried about the overhead of the MPPT controller for such small voltage and power.

Another solution I had in mind is getting off the shelve boost dc converters to bring all the cells to the same voltage, then again ideal diode, and parallel. But I think that would be very inefficient.

Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what is your question? ... it is unclear how a controller would cause the panels to generate more power

Comment: A single MPPT controller will not help you, as it needs to be able to track the MPP for each individual panel to have the most effect (especially as they're at different angles to the sun).

Comment: How much an MPPT controller contributes depends on how well the panels are matched to their load. Also, you may want to bypass/block panels/cells that are (almost) completely shaded. Out of curiosity: why are the panels at different angles and is there anything you can do about that?

Comment: Bypassing/blocking panels means power loss. I'd like to get the most power possible. Any reason why I'd want to bypass if I had MPPT for each panel?

@ocrdu the panels are all at different angles due to very limited space. I could lay them out flat, but then I'd fit only half of them.